# Why does appengine-rest-server return JSON strings even for integer properties?

Tags: json, google-app-engine, rest

I implemented a simple REST server on GAE using the appengine-rest-server. My DB schema looks like:

```
SomeString = db.StringProperty()
SomeInt = db.IntegerProperty(default=0)
SomeFloat = db.FloatProperty(default=-1.0)
SomeDateTime = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

When I do a Get with JSON output specified, I receive something like:

```
"EntityName":
{
    "SomeString": "Text"
    "SomeInt": "1"
    "SomeFloat": "1.0"
    "SomeDateTime": "2011-06-16T23:48:19.136146"
}
```

Any insight as to why the Int, Float and DateTime aren't correctly formatted as a such in the output? Does appengine-rest-server only output strings?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's because behind the scenes, appengine-rest-server uses xml for all of it's work.  It then converts to JSON if it sees that in the accept-header.  So, when it converts from xml, it's all strings.

Comment: the 1.0.6 release should fix this issue.